# Error while Registering the script to be run at start-up, how to resolve?

Tags: python

I am from electrical engineering and currently working on a project using **UP-Board**, I have attached LEDs, switch, Webcam, USB flash drive with it. I have created an **executable script** that I want to **run at startup**.

when I try to run the script in terminal using the code `sudo /etc/init.d/testRun start` it runs perfectly. Now when I write this command in terminal `sudo update-rc.d testRun defaults` **to register the script to be run at startup** it gives me the following error

> insserv: warning: script 'testRun' missing LSB tags and overrides

Please guide me how to resolve this? I am from Electrical engineering background, so novice in this field of coding. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think `https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts` describes the tags that the error message is referring to.  Their main purpose is to describe dependencies, so that (for example) a startup script that relies on networking runs after the one that sets up networking.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that you run the script as you but like chron startup does not, so you need to:

1. Ensure that the executable flags are set for all users and that it is in a directory that everybody has access to.
2. Use the absolute path for every thing, including the script.
3. Specify what to run it with, again with the absolute path.